# Excel VBA - How to alter the value of multiple cells inputted by the user?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet on Excel in which the user must input some registration numbers in column C. These numbers are usually inserted by the user by copying a pasting several of them at a time. The format of the copy source is often in the format "000.000.000-00", but I want it to be just "00000000000" in the worksheet, without the dots and dash.

I am trying to develop a code in Excel VBA to automatically remove these dots and dash after the user types or paste the registration number. I need it to be in the same cell. The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SkipEvents As Boolean
    If SkipEvents Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Staff")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        SkipEvents = True
        li = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")).Row
        nl = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")).Rows.Count
        lf = li + nl - 1

        For i = li To lf
            RegNumb = Range("C" & i).Value
            If Len(RegNumb) = 14 Then
                Range("C" & i).Value = Left(RegNumb, 3) & Mid(RegNumb, 5, 3) & Mid(RegNumb, 9, 3) & Right(RegNumb, 2)
            End If
        Next i
        SkipEvents = False
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

So far, the code is able to remove the dots and dash if the user types or copy+paste one registration number at a time. However, when the user copy+paste 2 or more registraton numbers at a time, only the first cell from the range have its dots and dash removed, and the others stay as they are. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: It looks as though you are iterating over the string. You may find it easier to `Replace(Replace(string, ".", ""), "-", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first cell in the range is being changed by your code because you are not iterating over the range. You could instead do this:

```
For each c in Target
    if c.column = 3 then 
         c.value = Replace(Replace(c.value, ".", ""), "-", "")
    end if
Next c
```

inside your Worksheet_Change.

Comment: @Cojonni So maybe you have done `Application.EnableEvents = False` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace directly on the entire desired range. You'll also need to Disable Events from firing since the changes you make will again fire the code. Also, since it's sheet level code, no need to refer to the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCheck as Range
    Set rCheck = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C"))

    If Not rCheck is Nothing

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rCheck.Replace(".","",lookat:=xlPart)
        rCheck.Replace("-","",lookat:=xlPart)
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If


End Sub
```

I will also warn that if the data set being checked is very large, this replace method can have poor performance. However, if copy / paste is relatively small in terms of cell counts, it should be fine.